# Create document not working - C# DocumentDB/CosmosDB

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I think I am on the right path, but my C# code is not creating document in Azure CosmosDB.
Below is my documentdb code:

```
using (var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpoint), authkey))
{
    Database database = client.CreateDatabaseQuery("SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id = 'db'").AsEnumerable().First();
    var query = new SqlQuerySpec
    {
        QueryText = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id = @id",
        Parameters = new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.SqlParameterCollection { new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.SqlParameter { Name = "@id", Value = collectionId }
    }
};

DocumentCollection collection = client.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery(database.SelfLink,query).AsEnumerable().First();

dynamic document1Definition = new
{
    name = "Admin",
    address = 1,
};

var result = client.CreateDocumentAsync(collection.SelfLink, document1Definition);

}
```

Also want to point out, currently there are **no columns named as "name" and "address" in my collection**. So according to my knowledge they are suppose to be created dynamically. Please let me know what wrong are you doing?

Comment: On a side not, it might worth talking a look at [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut). It supports all the C# SDK functionality in a more tidied up way. You could simply do a `await store.AddAsync(document1Definition)` and it would work. Disclaimer, I created this library.

Comment: I just ran the code (I only added a `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` at the end of the `CreateDocumentAsync` (which is not what you should do, you should use await but anyway)) from the post locally and it works like a charm btw. Could it be that you're using a Read-Only key?

Answer (score 3):

See last statement, you are using c# Async method without await.

Use `await client.CreateDocumentAsync(collection.SelfLink, document1Definition);` or your code will exit before document creation is finished.

Note that your method should change to `public async Task methodname()`, you will see related tip shown by VS.

Some references for you

- [Async and Await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index#BKMK_AsyncandAwait)
- [How and when to use async and-await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await)

Comment: If I add await, the web page keeps on loading. The execution doesn't complete nor throws any error.

Comment: @ZhrezPain Could you describe how you call this method(or show some related context) in your web app? Your code works in console application.